# Phonegap canvas not drawing on android but works fine in browser

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cordova

I've made a simple HTML5 noughts and crosses(tic tac toe) game that uses the canvas element and I am trying to use phonegap to get it working on Android. I've test it works fine on firefox, chrome and internet explorer but when I get built using phonegap the apk produced simply renders a white screen.

I've tried using the ripple emulator and it renders and behaves as expected fine. Really confused as to why its not working.

To work on pc instead of phoengap you have to change 
`document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);`
to
`document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onDeviceReady, false);`

in main.js.

I am using fast-canvas as a plugin, see the config file. 
Code is avaliable here as well as assets here: https://github.com/JacobRawling/XandOs
Please help I am very confused and am struggling to find any phonegap tutorials that use 
canvas.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is jqscribble – A touch enabled canvas drawing tool

http://plugins.jquery.com/jqscribble/